# Why does a connection from my LAN to my public IP address fails?

Tags: networking, iptables, routing

[image]

I have an OpenVPN server on `server`. It is available from Internet via a two NATs: first the ISP box relays to `192.168.0.10`, then `192.168.0.10` relays to  `10.10.10.254` (relays = DNAT).

- I can connect fine from Internet to the OpenVPN service
- I can ping from 10.10.10.20 a host on Internet and all the IPs above (including my public IP)
- Packets leaving my LAN at masqueraded at `eth0`

But **I cannot successufuly connect to the OpenVPN server from `10.10.10.20`** targeting `Public_IP` (the exact same connection which works from Internet - form the same physical laptop with the same configuration).
What direction should I be looking at to troubleshoot this problem?

While I have control over `laptop`and `server`, the `ISP box` is a closed black box. A packet leaving `10.10.10.20` is forwarded by `eth0` to `eth1` which routes to the default gateway `192.160.0.254` masquerading it on the way.

If this is a problem with the ISP box the bad luck, this is not critical. If this is a problem with my `iptables` rules then I would be glad to understand what to investigate.

The log from OpenVPN on `10.10.10.20`

```
Sun Apr 03 20:05:05 2016 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on Feb  1 2016
Sun Apr 03 20:05:05 2016 Windows version 6.2 (Windows 8 or greater)
Sun Apr 03 20:05:05 2016 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1r  28 Jan 2016, LZO 2.09
Sun Apr 03 20:05:05 2016 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Sun Apr 03 20:05:05 2016 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Sun Apr 03 20:05:05 2016 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Sun Apr 03 20:05:05 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Sun Apr 03 20:05:05 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Sun Apr 03 20:05:05 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Sun Apr 03 20:05:05 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Sun Apr 03 20:05:05 2016 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Sun Apr 03 20:05:05 2016 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1459706705,RESOLVE,,,
Sun Apr 03 20:05:05 2016 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Sun Apr 03 20:05:05 2016 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]Public_IP:1194
Sun Apr 03 20:05:05 2016 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1459706705,WAIT,,,
Sun Apr 03 20:05:05 2016 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1459706705,AUTH,,,
Sun Apr 03 20:05:05 2016 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]Public_IP:1194, sid=44ff9c3d ebf679d7
```

where `Public_IP` is the actual IP.

A `tcpdump` on all the interfaces of `srv` show the following traffic (one UDP stream). Sorry for the changed IP, `10.10.10.21` is the same as `10.10.10.20` above.

[image]